# Does ElementData have less information than Element Entity?

Tags: entity

```
Sort[ElementData[EntityClass["Element", "Radioactive"], "Name"]] == 
 Sort[EntityValue[EntityClass["Element", "Radioactive"], "Name"]]
```

gives True

However, `EntityValue` gives more complete information when querying "Density"

[image]

Is it a bug in `ElementData`? Does `EntityValue` design to give more complete data than `*Data` function? So are we encouraged to use `EntityValue` instead of using `*Data`?