# How to prevent output of Entity object in EntityValue?

Tags: output-formatting, entity

By default, no matter

```
ElementData["Hydrogen", "DiscoveryCountries"]
```

or

```
EntityValue[Entity["Element", "Hydrogen"], "DiscoveryCountries"]
```

gives

[image]

However, preparing and rendering Entity object is quite slow as said in [Speed of curated data calls in Version 10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56172/4742), a solution we can use is

```
SetSystemOptions[SystemOptions["DataOptions"] /. True -> False]
```

which results

```
{"DataOptions" -> {"ReturnEntities" -> False, "ReturnQuantities" -> False, 
"UseDataWrappers" -> False}}
```

to prevent output of entity object.

However, I found this only works for `*Data` function, not working for `EntityValue` query.

```
SetSystemOptions[SystemOptions["DataOptions"] /. True -> False]
ElementData["Hydrogen", "DiscoveryCountries"]
EntityValue[Entity["Element", "Hydrogen"], "DiscoveryCountries"]
```

gives

[image]

How to prevent output of Entity object of `EntityValue`? And combine with my [previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/265096/4742), it seems that `EntityValue` and `*Data` are unexpectedly inconsistent.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`$PrePrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html) and [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) with either [`ToString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) or [`CanonicalName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CanonicalName.html).

Before setting `$PrePrint`

```
SessionTime[];
ConstantArray[Entity["Country", "Bermuda"], 10000]
SessionTime[] - Out[-2]
```

takes 1.0735404 seconds to render the 10,000 entity objects.

I use [`Interpretation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpretation.html) to ensure the reformatted entities can still used. [`Pane`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html) provides formatting and spacing when reformatted entities are used in input.

With `ToString`

```
$PrePrint =
 Replace[#
   , e_Entity :> 
    Interpretation[Pane[ToString[e], ContentPadding -> False], e]
   , Infinity
   ] & ;
```

Now

```
SessionTime[];
ConstantArray[Entity["Country", "Canada"], 10000]
SessionTime[] - Out[-2]
```

takes 0.1586101 seconds to render the 10,000 reformatted entity objects.

These objects can still be used as entities and even copied and pasted as input.

> [image]

With `CanonicalName` it is slightly faster that `ToString`.

```
$PrePrint =
  Replace[#
    , e_Entity :> 
     Interpretation[Pane[CanonicalName[e], ContentPadding -> False], e]
    , Infinity
    ] &;
```

then

```
SessionTime[];
ConstantArray[Entity["Country", "Nigeria"], 10000]
SessionTime[] - Out[-2]
```

takes 0.1426487 seconds to render the 10,000 reformatted entity objects.

Still can be used for input

> [image]

`$PrePrint` can be cleared with

```
$PrePrint =.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great trick! I never used `Interpretation` before, a good lesson for me. But it seems that `Interpretation[ToString[e]], e]` is already enough and even faster. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. However, I did not like the fact that copying and pasting that output into an input cell gives a string. It looks better to me to have the entity statement in a pane without string quotes.

Comment: Ok, I understand the necessity of `Pane` now, thank you so much.

Comment: @matheorem Forgot to mention that you can use [`CanonicalName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CanonicalName.html) instead of `ToString` for a shorter descriptive string.

Comment: Thank you for mention, it seems that `CanonicalName` is what `*Data` function use after SetSystemOptions.